# OpenCart website doesn't open until the admin is online

Tags: opencart, admin, panel

I'm using `OpenCart` to create my online marketplace.

There is a problem with my website. It won't load until the admin is logged in to the admin panel. I even have this problem on `localhost`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Check under your settings `system > settings > (yourstore) > server` for an option called maintenance mode. If this is set to yes then that's your problem. If not what errors are you getting when navigating to the homepage without logging in as an admin? (check error log and enable the website to [show errors](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=38186&p=193157)).